# 2015 MacBook Air display awake while lid closed

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, mac, sleep-wake, google-chrome

I want my late 2015 MacBook Air to remain awake when the lid is closed. I have tried Caffeine, Stay Awake, and Theine, as well as changing my power saving settings to 'never' but nothing seems to work. The display still turns off when the lid is closed. Does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine did it when we saw a movie this weekend.
He used my TV as monitor and of course I asked him for a tutorial.

He sent me this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbWQuswykec

I will try it tomorrow. I hope it be helpful for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried Caffeine, but it did not work. What seems to work for me is to have the laptop plugged in. It should not go to sleep.